Proving the lower bound of maximum normalized cross correlation
The normalized cross-correlation (NCC) between any arbitrary 2 signals is ranged between 1 and -1. However, for the application of template matching, it is a usual practice to use the arg max to pick the lag and the NCC value where NCC is maximum.
In my understanding taking the max of NCC will make the lowest possible bound 0 instead of -1, because if a negative cross-correlation happens at some lag, the full range of zero padding of signal1 vs signal2 will ensure that the max NCC will always be >= 0.
This is a code snippet for calculating the max NCC:
import numpy as np

a -= np.mean(a)
b -= np.mean(b)
a /= np.linalg.norm(a)
b /= np.linalg.norm(b)
c  = np.correlate(a, b, mode = 'full')
result = np.max(c)

Note the mode = 'full' that will ensure full sweep of the signal by using zero padding:
https://numpy.org/doc/2.1/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html
I searched a bit to answer my question but most resources speak about the lower bound of NCC being -1 and not about max NCC which may differ.
Edit 2: I am interested in continuous signals just as much as discrete signals with a reasonably high sampling rate for the project's needs. I think the mathematical representation of continuous signals is the ideal way to model most biological and physical signals. Discretization inevitably leads to deviation in some properties from the continuous signal that we are trying to represent such as quantization errors, aliasing or the need for low pass filtering to eliminate the high freq. components, and several other limitations.
Edit:
I can't reply with figures, so here is my reply for @Hilmar's answer:

Nope. Just consider two signals that are phase flipped. If y(t)=−x(t)
then rxy(t)=−1∀t Just run your code with b = -a and see what you get.

Even with such an example, it will be 0. Here is a Matlab  example:
x1 = 1:0.001:50;
x2 = -1*x1;
[r, lags] = xcorr(x1,x2, 'normalized');
figure()
plot(lags,r)
 
max(r)
 
ans =
 
  -1.2000e-06

The small negative value is because of aliasing I think. With an ideal continuous signal, it will be 0. For example, with higher sampling rate, the result will approach zero asymptotically:
changing into 100x sampling rate:
x1 = 1:0.00001:50;
x2 = -1*x1;
[r, lags] = xcorr(x1,x2, 'normalized');
figure()
plot(lags,r)

max(r)

ans =

  -1.2000e-08


Note how the NCC is approaching 0 when the lag is minimum or max. I think that is the effect of computing NCC with the 'full' mode of padding, and hence the lower bound of max NCC is always >=0


In my understanding ... the max NCC will always be >= 0

Nope. Just consider two signals that are phase flipped. If $y(t) = -x(t)$ then $r_{xy}(t) = -1 \forall t$. When implementing this in discrete time you need to deal with edge effects, zero padding, etc. but you will still end up with $r_{xy}[n] < 0$ for any non-zero integration or summation interval.
Just run your code with b = -a and see what you get.

Thanks for your reply.
I don't think so! I edited my question to post a reply with a figure.

That's not a counter example. The max IS negative. It's close to zero but it's meaningfully smaller than 0. A better example would be xcorr(ones(10,1),-ones(10,1),'normalized') where the maximum is -0.1. The longer the signal, the closer to 0 it gets, but it will never actually BE zero or positive

I see. But if we look at your example as a continuous signal that has been discretized, I am curious, will the max cross-correlation be 0 if we compute NCC on these continuous two signals?
x1 = ones(100000,1);
x2 = -ones(100000,1);
will have a max of -1.0000e-05, so it seems with an infinite sampling rate (i.e., continuous) the max NCC will be zero?

I guess for a continuous signal of finite length, the cross correlation will always be zero if the overlap is zero. In other words the cross correlation will always start and end in 0, so in this case you are correct. Things are probably different with signals of infinite length but than the normalization becomes more tricky too.

This is what I wanted to confirm. I added 'Edit2' to my question. Apologies that I was not clear. If you're able to edit your answer, I will accept it.
